# Prolog Euclidian Square

Tags: prolog, tail-recursion, euclidean-distance

Ive written a program such that for two arrays X & Y that are equal it should calculate SUM((X-Y)*(X-Y)). However it just returns false:

```
euclidsqr([],[],ED).
euclidsqr([X|Xs],[Y|Ys],ED) :- euclidsqr(Xs,Ys,ED),ED is (X-Y)*(X-Y).
```

Comment: You here use `ED` for two purposes: for `ED` in the head, and for the recursiv case.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems here:

your version for two empty lists should unify the second parameter with `0`, not `ED`, since then it remains a *free* variable, so:

```
euclidsqr([], [], 0).
```

you also use `ED` to unify the result (in the head of the clause), but you use the same variable in the recursive call (on the tails of the list), furthermore you do not sum up the result of the recursive call, with `(X-Y)*(X-Y)`:

```
euclidsqr([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], ED) :-
    euclidsqr(Xs, Ys, ED1),
    ED is ED1 + (X-Y)*(X-Y).
```

or putting this together:

```
euclidsqr([], [], 0).
euclidsqr([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], ED) :-
    euclidsqr(Xs, Ys, ED1),
    ED is ED1 + (X-Y)*(X-Y).
```

Comment: I see, I did try something similar with euclidsqr(Xs,Ys,ED1),ED1 is ED + (X-Y)*(X-Y). But evidently this didn't work.